# How to achieve iteration control in apache jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I was working with IBM RPT, in RPT we can have iteration control, means you can execute definite number of loops for fixed time, e.g, I can have 30 loops (iterations) for 30 minutes. How can we achieve this scenario in jmeter?

Comment: @Ubik Load Pack...thanks for quick answer and sorry for late reply... I tried solution provided by you. with this i was able to run test for desired time but concurrency was not able to maintained also for few request number of samples are more than iteration value and for few, sample generated are less. I also need to maintain concurrency and iteration (loop) value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for that [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) component.

> This timer introduces variable pauses, calculated to keep the total throughput (in terms of samples per minute) as close as possible to a give figure

Or use [ThroughputShapingTimer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Comment: ..constant throughput timer solved my problem.. Thank u so much for ur answer.